# Node.js, WebSocket, prevent user from changing the wrong data

Tags: javascript, node.js

**EDIT: Actually i'm not sure exactly if Nodejs has his own data split system to prevent such bug from happening. So i need someone to answer me if i am wrong.. thank you for your time.**

So i'm coding a real time chess game in a browser.

My nodejs server. (I cut it short to decrease reading time)

```html
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const port = 6969;
const server = http.createServer(express);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    server
});

clients = [];
// That array contains the figure positions for all users connected.
// It is array that contains arrays. EXAMPLE:
// Each user has his own userid, username, and the figure position in each array:
// clients {
//   [0] = {'51', 'Diablo', '5'}
//   [1] = {'84', 'Jason', '3'}
//   [2] = {'15', 'Triston', '8'}
// }

// When user makes a move, a data is sent.
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws){
    ws.on('message', function incoming(data){
      // An user with ID 84, is sending his new figure position '13'.
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      // Now we need for loop in the clients array, to find the array index of the player
      // with ID of 84, in order to replace the old figure position in that index with
      // the new figure position.
      change_figure_position(data[0]);
    });
});

function change_figure_position(userid){
  var user_data;
  // looping trough all currently connected users.
  for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    // Upon each loop, check if the array index of 0 (the user id) matches
    // with the id of the user that send data.
    if(clients[i][0].includes(userid) == true){
      // The user index is found! Change the figure position in that index.
      clients[i][2] = data[2];
    }
  }
}
```

The code above explains it all, as i added comments everywhere. The code works perfectly, but my problem is different. As much as i know, Nodejs doesn't work like PHP. In PHP, when users keep executing same type of code, the PHP executes one request, and doesn't start executing the other without finishing the execution of the first. But in Nodejs, everything works in real time. The thing that worries me here is the following. Since Nodejs works in realtime, and doesn't wait for the first request to finish. Two users can send data at the same time.

If an user disconnects from my game, then his array that contains his data is removed from my clients variable. In that case the index numbers change. What if the function change_player_figure is called by a client, while another client disconnects at the same time? The following will happen.

```html
#current status of the clients variable
clients {
 [0] = {'51', 'Diablo', '5'}
 [1] = {'84', 'Jason', '3'}
 [2] = {'15', 'Triston', '8'}
 [3] = {'16', 'Jimmie', '5'}
}

// user Triston moves a figure
// the function finds that his index is [2]

// an user called Jason disconnects AT THE SAME TIME Triston moves a figure
#current status of the clients variable
clients {
 [0] = {'51', 'Diablo', '5'}
 [1] = {'15', 'Triston', '8'}
 [2] = {'16', 'Jimmie', '5'}
}

// remember, Triston disconected before the function FULLY executed itself
// the function still remembers that Triston's index is [2], but now it is [1].
// so what will happen is that Jimmie's figure will be moved instead.
```

That was my question. Since Nodejs works in real time, is it possible for bugs like this to happen? Sadly i have no idea how to test this out. On one side, the code works, that doesn't mean everything is allright. I had to ask this question. I hope someone with more experience is able to answer me or give me advice what i should do if this bug is possible to occur. Thank you for your time.

Comment: each javascript statement is executed after the previous one finishes - just like PHP ... "real time" is not a relevant term ... if you had some asynchronous calls or something, then that may be a challenge, but .. you don't seem to have anything like that in your code - the code in the event handler is asynchronous, but that isn't an issue, the whole code will execute before another event can be handled

Comment: I spend 1 day wondering if i am right or wrong about my doubt, but i hope you are right. I will read up some more and keep doing what i am doing. Thank you for your time.